# How do I add a header to a MEF call

Tags: silverlight, header, mef

I have a silverlight application where I download xaps using MEF. I would like to put a authorization token in the header of the call so that not anyone will be able to reach the xaps. Something like this:

```
catalog = new DeploymentCatalog(_uri);
catalog.AddHeader(_header);
catalog.DownloadAsync();
```

Only problem is that there is no AddHeader method.

Answer (score 1):

`DeploymentCatalog` uses `WebClient` under the hood, but doesn't seem to expose it in any way.

There's a copy of the source [here](http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/7218692) (couldn't find it on CodePlex for some reason). The URI is used by the `WebClient` to perform an asynchronous download. On completion, the response is used to create a collection of assemblies using `Package.LoadPackagedAssemblies`. Composition is performed using those assemblies.

Some of the relevant code:

```
//the download
this.WebClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(HandleOpenReadCompleted);
this.WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(HandleDownloadProgressChanged);
this.WebClient.OpenReadAsync(Uri, this);

//composition on completion of async download
var assemblies = Package.LoadPackagedAssemblies(e.Result);
this.DiscoverParts(assemblies);
```

You could create a custom catalog that does the same thing but provides an AddHeader method, or exposes the `WebClient`, or whatever.